# Servlet-Apache Tomcat

Tags: java, apache, tomcat

Need help.
I am using `JDK 1.7` & `Tomcat 7`
I am trying to start the tomcat sever but cant see the Home page of apache tomcat.
I have over looked the log file & got this log :

```
Jul 21, 2015 4:24:30 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Server version:        Apache Tomcat/7.0.63  
Jul 21, 2015 4:24:30 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Server built:          Jun 30 2015 08:08:33 UTC  
Jul 21, 2015 4:24:30 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Server number:         7.0.63.0  
Jul 21, 2015 4:24:30 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: OS Name:               Windows 7  
Jul 21, 2015 4:24:30 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: OS Version:            6.1  
Jul 21, 2015 4:24:30 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Architecture:          amd64  
Jul 21, 2015 4:24:30 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Java Home:             C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_79\jre  
Jul 21, 2015 4:24:30 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: JVM Version:           1.7.0_79-b15  
Jul 21, 2015 4:24:30 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: JVM Vendor:            Oracle Corporation  
Jul 21, 2015 4:24:30 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: CATALINA_BASE:         C:\apache-tomcat-7.0.63\apache-tomcat-7.0.63
Jul 21, 2015 4:24:30 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: CATALINA_HOME:         C:\apache-tomcat-7.0.63\apache-tomcat-7.0.63  

SEVERE: ContainerBase.addChild: start:   
org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component   [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/docs]]  

Jul 21, 2015 4:24:31 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory  
SEVERE: Error deploying web application directory C:\apache-tomcat-7.0.63\apache-tomcat-7.0.63\webapps\docs  
java.lang.IllegalStateException: ContainerBase.addChild: start:   org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component   [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/docs]]
```

Comment: It might be permission issue. Give full access or permission to tomcat folder.

Comment: Your JAVA_HOME points to a JRE.  I wonder if it should point to a JDK instead?  All mine do.

Comment: Are you using linux?...if so then  You can check the permissions using the linux command ls -l.

Comment: @duffymo it should work fine with JRE as well.

Comment: Permissions can probably be the issue here because if your environment variables were not set correctly, you wouldn't have even seen these much lines. Try not keeping your tomcat installation in Program Files and Program Files (x86) directories if working with windows.

Answer (score 0):

My initial thinking is that your Tomcat installation you are using is not a fresh install. Try and follow these steps:

1. Download your preffered copy from: http://tomcat.apache.org/download-70.cgi
2. Extract it to a given folder
3. Use the startup script to start the service.

Answer (score 0):

You have to set path for the Apache Tomcat:

**CATALINA_HOME = "where you kept your tomcat directory "**

then restart the server. open browser type **http://localhost:8080**

Answer (score 0):

To start Tomcat set two environment variables:

- JAVA_HOME: This refers to the directory in which java and javac are present
  example: C:\jdk1.8.0_181
- CATALINA_HOME: This refers to the directory above the bin
  example: C:\apache-tomcat-5.5.29

Then open Command Prompt and run the following command:
%CATALINA_HOME%\bin\startup.bat

If you don't set CATALINA_HOME then
C:\apache-tomcat-5.5.29\bin\statup.bat

Then open your web browser and type:
localhost:8080

Recheck the settings you have done.

For more details refer:
https://www.tutorialspoint.com/jsp/jsp_environment_setup.htm